# ERROR DE CORS DESDE VUE CLI

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-8, cors, vue-cli

quería consultar sobre este error que me aparece el siguiente error a la hora de hacer un fetch. [image: Error-fetch]

Estoy trabajando con Laravel 8 y cree el siguiente Middleware para que me permita hacer las peticiones.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuestion.. cuando hago un PUT o DELETE desde POSTMAN me lo deja realizar sin ningún tipo de problema y se actualiza en la base de datos.

Pero cuando lo realizo desde la pagina no me deja hacer el PUT o DELETE del item.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo porque me deja desde el postman pero cuando trabajo desde la pagina que estoy realizando con VueCli no me deja.

Perdon si no supe explicarme demasiado , soy bastante nuevo en esto.

Comment: Por favor coloca el código como texto. Las imágenes de código no ayudan

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Las peticiones de dominio cruzado (CORS) no son válidas en los navegadores dado que son bloqueadas por considerarse un fallo de seguridad.

Si miramos la documentación de un navegador (en este caso Mozilla) nos dicen que:

> Por razones de seguridad, los exploradores restringen las solicitudes HTTP de origen cruzado iniciadas dentro de un script. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Te recomiendo intentar cambiar el endpoint en el frontend para que apunte a localhost:8080 en lugar de a 127.0.0.1

Aunque localhost y 127.0.0.1 sean lo mismo, para la validación de CORS se establece domain + ports, quizás está saltando el warning por ese motivo.